# Calculating the occurrence of unknown values in a list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I very often face the following problem:

I have a list with unknown elements in it (but each element is of the same type, e.g.: str) and I want to count the occurrence of each element. Sometime I also want to do something with the occurrence values, so I usually store them in a dictionary.

My problem is, that I cannot "auto initialize" a dictionary with `+=1`, so I first I have to do a check, if the given element is still in the dictionary.

My usual go to solution:

```
dct = {}    
for i in iterable:
    if i in dct:
        dct[i] += 1
    else:
        dct[i] = 1
```

Is there a simpler colution to this problem?

Comment: Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and then `counts = Counter(iterable)`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Exactly what I was searching for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! A `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(int)

for i in iterable:
    dict[i] += 1
```

---

You can auto-initialise with other types too:

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

```
d = defaultdict(str)
d[i] += 'hello'
```

---

If you're just counting things, you could use a `Counter` instead:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(iterable)  # c is a subclass of dict
```